# reference a cell value inside a formula (indirect)

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, reference, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

please I need help with indirect (reference a cell value) and use that value in a formula

hi, as you know, array formulas get crazy with thousands of rows for no reason, so I want to limit my arrays using a referenced cell value using indirect, but I always fail to write it right for some reason.

```
=COUNTA(L2:L)
```

this gives me the value I need = reference value

now I want to reference that cell value inside a formula like

```
=UNIQUE(M2:M reference)
```

---

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(M2:M reference;UNIQUE(P2:P reference)))
```

I know I have to use indirect, but the syntax always fails for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(M2:M&P2:P), COUNTIF(M2:M, P2:P), ))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("M2:M"&COUNTA(M2:M)+1), 
                      INDIRECT("P2:P"&COUNTA(P2:P)+1)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: YES, that did it. thanks a lot kind sir. worked fine. i will use this a lot since my arrayformulas get crazy, they go up to 50000 rows just like crazy